# jquery ui datepicker - have to leave field and then click again to show datepicker

Tags: jquery, user-interface, datepicker

I have a small problem with a jquery ui datepicker. If I click on the input type text then the datepicker shows and I select a date. The input then gets focus which means I have to click outside the input and then click it again to show the datepicker. This problem doesnt appear on the datepicker demo... you can just keep clicking it http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/

--

No errors in console

--

```
  // hangout date - jquery ui timepicker
  $("#hangout_date").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'D d M yy' });

<p id="hangout_date_container">
  <%= f.label :startdate, "Start Date" %>
  <br />
  <input type="text" id="hangout_date" name="hangout_date" size="30" value="" />
</p>
```

Comment: Are you receiving any JS errors in the console?

Comment: and can we see your curent code please.

Comment: try to add showOn: "focus" on you datepicker options, and see if this works.

$("#hangout_date").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'D d M yy', showOn: "focus" });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply updating from jquery ui 1.8.15 to 1.8.16 fixed it. Sorry should have done that before wasting your time.